# How to find distinct sum of a column in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this structure:

```
 lineID  lineItemPrice
    1            20
    2            25
    3            27
    4            30
    4            30 
    4            30
```

I want to get the sum of lineItemPrice where lineId is distinct.
I am not sure what should be sql query? Please help.

The output should be 102.

Comment: So what should be the output?

Comment: @TechDo: Output should be one value the total sum.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy, I've got all the answers summed up in one. :)  If you are looking for the total sum, see my number 3 query.  TechDo's answer is like my #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant quite tell if you are looking for this:

```
select
   sum(lineItemPrice), lineID
from
   table
group by lineID
```

Or this:

```
select
   sum(lineItemPrice)
from
   (select distinct lineID, lineItemPrice from table)
```

If you want the sum of the whole table:

```
select
   sum(lineItemPrice)
from
   table
```

The first would give results that would sum up all the lineItemPrice's for their respective lineID's

```
 lineID  lineItemPrice
    1            20
    2            25
    3            27
    4            90
```

The second would sum all these distinct records giving **102** as the answer

```
 lineID  lineItemPrice
    1            20
    2            25
    3            27
    4            30
```

The third:

```
lineItemPrice
   162
```

Comment: I need only one value that is the total sum of  lineItemPrice

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy I think the third query returns 162 as sum. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(lineItemPrice) as TotalSum FROM
(SELECT lineItemPrice
FROM TableName
GROUP BY lineID,lineITemPrice) T
```

Result:

```
TOTALSUM
102
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7461/12).

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
    SUM(lineItemPrice) lineItemPrice 
from(
    select 
        distinct lineID, lineItemPrice 
    From tbl
)x
```

You can use below query if lineID lineITemPrice for a same value pair.

```
select
    SUM(DISTINCT lineItemPrice) lineItemPrice 
From tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
Select  lineID, SUM(lineItemPrice) Total From YourTableName Group By lineID
```

Very Simple.

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions (we used SUM function here) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Answer (score 0):

Why Not this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
Select  lineID, SUM(lineItemPrice) Over(Partition By lineID) Total 
From TableName 
  ) T
Group By lineID,Total
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f7461/24)**

Output:

```
  lineID     lineItemPrice
    1            20
    2            25
    3            27
    4            90
```